# What is the difference between adonai and adoni?

Tags: hebrew, words, grammar-dikduk, shemos-sacred-names

I'm sure I've missed something quite obvious here, but I've always been told that adonai is "my Lord", and so I always assumed that it was adon with 'my' stuck to it. But, that would be adoni, with a hireq yod pronominal suffix, like in [Gen 23](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0123.htm#6) where the Hittites and then Efron address Avraham.  Or, if it is 'adonai' as a type 2 pronominal suffix, it would be a pathach yod, and not the qamets yod we see in the text like in [Gen 15:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0115.htm#2) where Avram addresses God. What have I missed?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15124/759

Answer (score 8):

chirik - adoni - "my [human] master"

patach - adonai - "my [human] masters"

komotz - adonoi - "my Lord-of-all-things" = God . Its own special grammatical construction specifically used for the name of God.

Comment: How are #2 and #3 different (in grammar)?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I don't think a kamatz-yud suffix is a thing anywhere else.

Comment: @DoubleAA "I don't think a kamatz-yud suffix is a thing anywhere else"? Does it mean, it does not exist anywhere else? What is the answer to the question, "How are #2 and #3 different (in grammar)?"

Comment: @DoubleAA, would this still hold true in a pausal form ?

Comment: @noach I've thought of that and agree that would be an ambiguous case. I feel like I saw an example once but don't recall where